# Grid From XML data

Tags: java, xml

I  have create jsp page to display grid from xml data. Below i have displayed my jsp(parsing jsp

) page and xml (display.xml)page.

### parsing.jsp

```
%@ page contentType="text/html"%> 

%@ page import="javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory, 

javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder,org.w3c.dom.*" 

%>  

% 

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); 

DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder(); 

Document doc = db.parse("http://10.100.133.106:50000/XMII/CM/Glory/Sample/display.xml"); 


NodeList nl= doc.getElementsByTagName("title"); 

NodeList n2= doc.getElementsByTagName("author"); 

NodeList n3= doc.getElementsByTagName("year");  

NodeList n4= doc.getElementsByTagName("price"); 

%>  

html> 

body><center> 

table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> 

tr>  

td style="background:#000033;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:bold;">Title/td> 

td style="background:#000033;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:bold;">Author/td> 

td style="background:#000033;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:bold;">Year/td> 

td style="background:#000033;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:bold;">Price/td> 

/tr> 

tr>  

<% 

for(int i=0;i<3;i++) 

{ 

%> 

<td><%= nl.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue() %></td> 

<td><%= n2.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue() %></td> 

<td><%= n3.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue() %></td> 

<td><%= n4.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue() %></td> 

</tr> 

<%  

} 

%> 
/table> 

/center> 

/body> 

/html>
```

### display.xml

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 

bookstore> 

book category="COOKING"> 

title lang="en">Everyday Italian/title> 

author>Giada De Laurentiis/author>  

year>2005/year> 

price>30.00/price> 

/book> 
book category="CHILDREN"> 

title lang="en">Harry Potter/title> 

author>J K. Rowling/author>  

year>2005/year> 

price>29.99/price> 

/book> 

book category="WEB"> 

title lang="en">Learning XML/title> 

author>Erik T. Ray/author>  

year>2003/year> 

\price>39.95/price> 

\book> 

\/bookstore>
```

While executing am getting following Error report.

> Error: "Application error occurred during the request processing."
>
> Troubleshooting Guide
>   https://sdn.sap.com/irj/sdn/wiki?path=/display/JSTS/Home
>
> Details:
>
> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The markup in the document following
>   the root element must be well-formed.        at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:264)
>   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:292)
>   at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:165)
>   at
>   JEE_jsp_CM_Glory_Sample_displayXML_8904750_1340860399234_1340860399922._jspService(JEE_jsp_CM_Glory_Sample_displayXML_8904750_1340860399234_1340860399922.java:51)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.lib.jspruntime.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:102)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.server.Invokable.invoke(Invokable.java:140)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.server.servlet.JSPServlet.service(JSPServlet.java:436)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.server.servlet.JSPServlet.service(JSPServlet.java:240)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.server.runtime.FilterChainImpl.runServlet(FilterChainImpl.java:162)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.server.runtime.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:81)
>   at com.sap.xmii.system.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:96)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.server.runtime.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:73)
>   at com.sap.xmii.system.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:96)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.server.runtime.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:73)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.server.HttpHandlerImpl.runServlet(HttpHandlerImpl.java:461)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.server.HttpHandlerImpl.handleRequest(HttpHandlerImpl.java:298)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.server.RequestAnalizer.startServlet(RequestAnalizer.java:397)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.server.RequestAnalizer.startServlet(RequestAnalizer.java:386)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.filters.DSRWebContainerFilter.process(DSRWebContainerFilter.java:48)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.filters.ServletSelector.process(ServletSelector.java:83)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.filters.ApplicationSelector.process(ApplicationSelector.java:243)        at
>   com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.filters.WebContainerInvoker.process(WebContainerInvoker.java:78)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.HostFilter.process(HostFilter.java:9)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.filters.ResponseLogWriter.process(ResponseLogWriter.java:60)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.HostFilter.process(HostFilter.java:9)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.filters.DefineHostFilter.process(DefineHostFilter.java:27)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.ServerFilter.process(ServerFilter.java:12)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.filters.MonitoringFilter.process(MonitoringFilter.java:29)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.ServerFilter.process(ServerFilter.java:12)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.filters.MemoryStatisticFilter.process(MemoryStatisticFilter.java:43)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.ServerFilter.process(ServerFilter.java:12)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.filters.DSRHttpFilter.process(DSRHttpFilter.java:42)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.ServerFilter.process(ServerFilter.java:12)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.server.Processor.chainedRequest(Processor.java:428)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.server.Processor$FCAProcessorThread.process(Processor.java:247)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.server.rcm.RequestProcessorThread.run(RequestProcessorThread.java:45)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.core.thread.execution.Executable.run(Executable.java:122)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.core.thread.execution.Executable.run(Executable.java:101)
>   at
>   com.sap.engine.core.thread.execution.CentralExecutor$SingleThread.run(CentralExecutor.java:327)

But xml data is well confirmed. Please solve this issue

Regards,

Comment: Please use `{}` for code formatting. I assume you did remove the `<` from your xml when posting your question?

Comment: Yes i removed < from xml then only it showed somewhat in xml fomat